# SQL Optimization query for recrusive subquery (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, knowledge-graph

I am totally new to MySQL and appreciate very much for your patience.
I have the following MySQL table:

| fact_id | from_id | relation_id | to_id | link_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19 | 6 | 151 | 1 |
| 2 | 2233 | 2 | 57 | 1 |
| 3 | 182 | 23 | 112 | 1 |
| 4 | 22 | 17 | 21 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 8 | 742 | 1 |
| 6 | 507 | 2 | 55 | 1 |
| 7 | 154 | 25 | 56 | 1 |
| 8 | 100 | 83 | 18 | 1 |
| 9 | 1110 | 2 | 31 | 1 |
| 10 | 141 | 29 | 7 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

with the corresponding init code:

```sql
create table icews14s
(
    fact_id     int auto_increment
        primary key,
    from_id     int not null,
    relation_id int not null,
    to_id       int not null,
    link_time   int not null
);

create index icews14s_from_id_index
    on icews14s (from_id);

create index icews14s_link_time_index
    on icews14s (link_time);

create index icews14s_to_id_index
    on icews14s (to_id);
```

and one long query:

```sql
with target as (select fact_id, from_id, link_time from icews14s where fact_id = 69298),
             pre_nodes_1 as (select o.fact_id     as fact_id,
                                    o.from_id     as from_id,
                                    o.relation_id as relation_id,
                                    o.to_id       as to_id,
                                    o.link_time   as link_time,
                                    1             as degree
                             from icews14s o
                                      left join (select * from icews14s) t
                                                on o.from_id = t.from_id and o.link_time < t.link_time
                             where t.fact_id in (select fact_id from target)),
             pre_nodes_2 as (select o.fact_id     as fact_id,
                                    o.from_id     as from_id,
                                    o.relation_id as relation_id,
                                    o.to_id       as to_id,
                                    o.link_time   as link_time,
                                    2             as degree
                             from icews14s o
                                      left join (select * from icews14s) t on o.from_id = t.to_id and o.link_time < t.link_time
                             where t.fact_id in (select fact_id from pre_nodes_1)),
             pre_nodes_3 as (select o.fact_id     as fact_id,
                                    o.from_id     as from_id,
                                    o.relation_id as relation_id,
                                    o.to_id       as to_id,
                                    o.link_time   as link_time,
                                    3             as degree
                             from icews14s o
                                      left join (select * from icews14s) t on o.from_id = t.to_id and o.link_time < t.link_time
                             where t.fact_id in (select fact_id from pre_nodes_2))
        select fact_id, from_id, relation_id, to_id, link_time, 0 as degree from icews14s where fact_id = 69298
        union select * from pre_nodes_1
        union select * from pre_nodes_2
        union select * from pre_nodes_3
        order by fact_id desc limit 30;
```

the corresponding result is :

| fact_id | from_id | relation_id | to_id | link_time | degree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 69298 | 1659 | 16 | 269 | 285 | 0 |
| 60977 | 1659 | 37 | 3176 | 253 | 1 |
| 58981 | 3176 | 1 | 3281 | 245 | 2 |
| 58757 | 1659 | 8 | 1884 | 245 | 1 |
| 58722 | 1659 | 0 | 1884 | 245 | 1 |
| 39282 | 1659 | 1 | 105 | 163 | 1 |
| 38740 | 105 | 7 | 1143 | 161 | 2 |
| 38570 | 105 | 29 | 1815 | 161 | 2 |
| 38440 | 105 | 19 | 2 | 160 | 2 |
| 38101 | 2 | 28 | 52 | 159 | 3 |
| 38061 | 105 | 0 | 581 | 158 | 2 |
| 37825 | 2 | 14 | 1057 | 157 | 3 |
| 37822 | 2 | 2 | 228 | 157 | 3 |
| 37606 | 2 | 2 | 1006 | 156 | 3 |
| 37597 | 2 | 9 | 9 | 156 | 3 |
| 37554 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 156 | 3 |
| 37390 | 2 | 99 | 9 | 156 | 3 |
| 37322 | 2 | 8 | 48 | 155 | 3 |
| 37277 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 155 | 3 |
| 37266 | 2 | 9 | 1068 | 155 | 3 |
| 37210 | 2 | 8 | 239 | 155 | 3 |
| 37120 | 2 | 2 | 90 | 155 | 3 |
| 37032 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 154 | 3 |
| 36993 | 2 | 8 | 28 | 154 | 3 |
| 36988 | 2 | 71 | 136 | 154 | 3 |
| 36971 | 2 | 2 | 90 | 154 | 3 |
| 36949 | 2 | 9 | 48 | 154 | 3 |
| 36896 | 2 | 29 | 9 | 154 | 3 |
| 36827 | 2 | 28 | 309 | 154 | 3 |
| 36798 | 2 | 10 | 52 | 153 | 3 |

The question is, this query is very slow in such a 100000 record table.

Is there any methods to make it quicker?

I tried to solve using recrusive temp table, but this statement never ends:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE pre_nodes AS (
    SELECT
        fact_id,
        from_id,
        relation_id,
        to_id,
        link_time,
        0 AS degree
    FROM
        icews14s
    WHERE
        fact_id = 69298
    UNION
    SELECT
        o.fact_id,
        o.from_id,
        o.relation_id,
        o.to_id,
        o.link_time,
        n.degree + 1
    FROM
        icews14s o
    JOIN
    pre_nodes n ON IF(n.degree = 0, (o.from_id = n.from_id AND o.link_time < n.link_time),
                      (o.from_id = n.to_id AND o.link_time < n.link_time))
    WHERE
        o.fact_id != 69298
)
SELECT distinct
    fact_id,
    from_id,
    relation_id,
    to_id,
    link_time,
    degree
FROM
    pre_nodes
ORDER BY
    fact_id DESC
LIMIT
    30;
```

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/) and then add the relevant information to your question, particularly the `EXPLAIN` and/or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for your query. A link to a working https://dbfiddle.uk will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Have you tried adding a composite index on `(from_id, link_time)`? The recursive cte may not use it, but it is worth a try. Also, changing the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` in the recursive cte.

Comment: You have this pattern `left join (select * from icews14s) t on o.from_id = t.from_id and o.link_time < t.link_time` several times. Do you get improved performance if you replace it with  `left join icews14s t on o.from_id = t.from_id and o.link_time < t.link_time` . Also, use `UNION ALL` everywhere you use `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone commenting on this problem, now I accelerated the SQL by adding `order by fact_id desc limit 30` after each degree of `pre_node`, the logic is slightly changed, but keeps useful and right for me. 

Appologize for my unfamiliarity with community norms and thanks for everyone again :-) every comment helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query can be simplified quite a bit. Let's take the `pre_nodes_1` cte as an example:

```sql
pre_nodes_1 as (
    select o.fact_id     as fact_id,
           o.from_id     as from_id,
           o.relation_id as relation_id,
           o.to_id       as to_id,
           o.link_time   as link_time,
           1             as degree
    from icews14s o
    left join (select * from icews14s) t
        on o.from_id = t.from_id
       and o.link_time < t.link_time
    where t.fact_id in (select fact_id from target)
)
```

As [O. Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77350102/sql-optimization-query-for-recrusive-subquery-mysql#comment136364836_77350102) pointed out in the comments, the nesting of `(select * from icews14s)` is unnecessary, but the optimizer ***should*** spot this and remove the nesting. The `left join` will be implicitly turned into an `inner join` due to the criterion on `t.fact_id`. Given the `t.fact_id in (select fact_id from target)`, I think the cte can be rewritten as:

```sql
pre_nodes_1 as (
    select o.*, 1 as degree
    from icews14s o
    join target t
        on o.from_id = t.from_id and o.link_time < t.link_time
)
```

The same pattern applies to the other two `pre_nodes_*` ctes. Given the `o.link_time < t.link_time` criterion in each of the joins, it should not be necessary to dedupe the `UNION`, so switching to `UNION ALL` will reduce overhead by removing the dedupe step.

```sql
with target as (
    select fact_id, from_id, link_time from icews14s where fact_id = 69298
),
pre_nodes_1 as (
    select o.*, 1 as degree
    from icews14s o
    join target t
        on o.from_id = t.from_id and o.link_time < t.link_time
),
pre_nodes_2 as (
    select o.*, 2 as degree
    from icews14s o
    join pre_nodes_1 t
        on o.from_id = t.to_id and o.link_time < t.link_time
),
pre_nodes_3 as (
    select o.*, 3 as degree
    from icews14s o
    join pre_nodes_2 t
        on o.from_id = t.to_id and o.link_time < t.link_time
)

select fact_id, from_id, relation_id, to_id, link_time, 0 as degree
from icews14s
where fact_id = 69298
union all
select * from pre_nodes_1
union all
select * from pre_nodes_2
union all
select * from pre_nodes_3
order by fact_id desc
limit 30;
```

This query will probably benefit from a composite index on `(from_id, link_time)`:

```sql
alter table icews14s
    add index idx_from_id_link_time (from_id, link_time);
```

For your recursive cte, I suspect the performance issue is due to the join condition. Without a reasonable amount of test data I cannot test this, but I suspect rewriting the recursive part of the cte like this ***may*** allow it to use an index:

```sql
    SELECT o.*, n.degree + 1
    FROM pre_nodes n
    JOIN icews14s o
        ON o.from_id = IF(n.degree = 0, n.from_id, n.to_id)
        AND o.link_time < n.link_time
        AND o.fact_id <> 69298
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these detailed and professional advices! I will try it later.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Note that if you have added the composite index on `(from_id, link_time)` you can drop the single column index on `(from_id)`, as it is now redundant.